# Experimentally verifying order of convergence of SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, python

I am trying to experimentally verify strong and weak orders of convergence of Euler-Maruyama and Milstein methods for the following SDE.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
dX_t&=9.5(Y_x-X_t)dt+(Y_t-X_t)dW_t\\
dY_t&=(28X_t-Y_T-X_tZ_t)dt\\
dZ_t&=(X_tY_t-\frac{8}{3}Z_t)dt
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

I got

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
X_{n+1}&=X_n+9.5(Y_n-X_n)\Delta t+(Y_n-X_n)\Delta W_n\\
Y_{n+1}&=Y_n+(28X_n-Y_n-X_nZ_n)\Delta t\\
Z_{n+1}&=Z_n+(X_nY_n-\frac{8}{3}Z_n)\Delta t
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

for Euler-Maruyama method and

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
X_{n+1}&=X_n+9.5(Y_n-X_n)\Delta t+(Y_n-X_n)\Delta W_n-0.5(Y_n-X_n)(\Delta W_n^2-\Delta t)\\
Y_{n+1}&=Y_n+(28X_n-Y_n-X_nZ_n)\Delta t\\
Z_{n+1}&=Z_n+(X_nY_n-\frac{8}{3}Z_n)\Delta t
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

for Milstein method.

I have set $[0,1]$ as the interval and $3.125\times10^{-4}$ as a reference $dt$ for approximating the exact solution since I do not think there is an analytic solution to the SDE above.

I have written following Python code to run experiments and plot graphs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x0 = 1.508870
y0 = -1.531271
z0 = 25.246091

t = 1
dt = 3.125e-4
n = int(t / dt)
sample_dts = np.power(2, np.arange(5, 0, -1)) * dt
number_of_samples = 10000

def euler_maruyama(a, dt, dw):
    x, y, z = a
    return np.array([x + 9.5 * (y - x) * dt + (y - x) * dw, y + (28 * x - y - x * z) * dt, z + (x * y - 8 / 3 * z) * dt])

def milstein(a, dt, dw):
    x, y, z = a
    return np.array([x + 9.5 * (y - x) * dt + (y - x) * dw - 0.5 * (y - x) * (dw ** 2 - dt), y + (28 * x - y - x * z) * dt, z + (x * y - 8 / 3 * z) * dt])

def simulate(initial_condition, step_function, weak=False):
    errors = np.zeros((len(sample_dts), len(initial_condition)))
    y = np.tile(initial_condition, (1, number_of_samples))
    x = np.tile(initial_condition, (len(sample_dts), 1, number_of_samples))
    if not weak:
        dw = np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(dt), size=(n, number_of_samples))
        for i in range(n):
            y = step_function(y, dt, dw[i])
            for j, sample_dt in enumerate(sample_dts):
                scale = int(sample_dt / dt)
                if i % scale == 0:
                    x[j] = step_function(x[j], sample_dt, np.sum(dw[i * scale:(i + 1) * scale], axis=0))
        errors = np.mean(np.abs(y - x), axis=2)
    else:
        for i in range(n):
            y = step_function(y, dt, np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(dt), size=number_of_samples))
        for i, sample_dt in enumerate(sample_dts):
            for j in range(int(1 / sample_dt)):
                x[i] = step_function(x[i], sample_dt, np.sqrt(sample_dt) * np.random.randn(number_of_samples))
        errors = np.abs(np.mean(y, axis=1) - np.mean(x, axis=2))
    return errors

euler_maruyama_strong_errors = simulate(np.array([x0, y0, z0]).reshape((3, 1)), euler_maruyama)
euler_maruyama_weak_errors = simulate(np.array([x0, y0, z0]).reshape((3, 1)), euler_maruyama, weak=True)

for i in range(3):
    ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax1.plot(sample_dts, euler_maruyama_strong_errors[:, i])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    ax2.plot(sample_dts, euler_maruyama_weak_errors[:, i])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

milstein_strong_errors = simulate(np.array([x0, y0, z0]).reshape((3, 1)), milstein)
milstein_weak_errors = simulate(np.array([x0, y0, z0]).reshape((3, 1)), milstein, weak=True)

for i in range(3):
    ax1 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    ax1.plot(sample_dts, milstein_strong_errors[:, i])
    ax2 = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    ax2.plot(sample_dts, milstein_weak_errors[:, i])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

def order_of_convergence(dts, errors):
    return np.linalg.lstsq(np.column_stack((np.ones(len(dts)), np.log(dts))), np.log(errors), rcond=None)[0][1]
```

I have learned that Euler-Maruyama method has strong order of convergence $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ and weak order of convergence $\Delta t$ and Milstein method has both strong and weak order of convergence $\Delta t$. I have also learned that Milstein method is better than Euler-Maruyama method in terms of magnitude of errors. And I am using following definitions for strong and weak order of convergence.

$$
E\{|X_T-X_N|\}<=K(\Delta t)^j\\
|E\{X_T\}-E\{X_N\}|<=K(\Delta t)^j
$$

However, running the code above and analyzing order of convergence using `order_of_convergence` function returns the following results.

|  | $x$ | $y$ | $z$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Euler-Maruyama strong order | 0.4126 | 0.3708 | 0.3154 |
| Euler-Maruyama weak order | 1.1720 | 1.1252 | 1.7638 |
| Milstein strong order | 0.4156 | 0.3686 | 0.3162 |
| Milstein strong order | 1.2197 | 1.1134 | 1.4276 |

Values do not match expectations and Milstein method is almost identical to Euler-Maruyama method and does not yield smaller magnitude of errors.

Is my Milstein equation wrong or experiment setup wrong?

Comment: You should consult the classic book by Kloeden & Platen. As far as I remember order of convergence applies to idealised situations and I also think that your non-linear system has not closed form solution. If it had your task would be straighforward.

Comment: The definiton of errors seems strange. The weak error is defined via testfunctions, which you miss. The strong error you define is only defined in $t=1$ but normally should be uniform in the sense it holds for every $t_i=i \cdot dt$ for all $i=0,...,N$. The strong error you implemented is again different from your definition.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine The weak error was indeed defined as $|E\{h(X_T,T)\}-E\{h(X_N,N)\}|<=K(\Delta t)^j$ but I just took $h(x,t)=x$. The full definition of strong order of convergence I was taught is this. The strong order of convergence is $j$ if there exists a positive constant $K$ and a positive constant $\Delta$ such that for fixed $T=N\Delta t$: $E\{|X_T-X_N|\}<=K(\Delta t)^j$ for all $0<\Delta t<\Delta$. I understood this as mean of errors at $T$. Is my implementation still wrong even with this definition?

Comment: The error definitions you give are ok. Even if a stronger statement than your definition holds, you should be able to reproduce your orders of convergence. I think your implementation of the errors is still wrong. Did you note that $|X|$ is a norm and no absolute value? In your case $|X|$ is the norm of a $3$ dimsenional vector.

Comment: A further error might be your $X_T$. You can't get it analiticaly so you have to solve it numerically. I think your $X_T$ is a numerical solution with the same stepsize as $X_N$ this can't work.

Comment: To see the correct convergence rates you need to rerun your setup for different $dt$. For example $dt=2^{-10},2^{-11},...,$ for $X_N$ and compute for the same paths a solution $X_T$ with $dt=2^{-24}$ or something like that.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine I was using $\Delta t=3.125\times10^{-4}$ to compute $X_T$ and $2\Delta t$, $4\Delta t$, $8\Delta t$, $16\Delta t$, and $32\Delta t$ for $X_N$. And for $|X|$, the example I saw was for scalar SDE and it used the term "absolute error" so I assumed that $|X|$ meant absolute value of $X$. Does this change to norm of $X$ when $X$ is a vector?

Comment: Ok nice thats a good start. Yes it changes, you can take any p-norm you want for example the euclidian norm. I think at the moment you take the mean of $abs(X_N-X_T)$ thats not what you want. When implementing the norm you should see that this mean does nothing.

Comment: You approximate $E(X)\approx\frac{1}{10000}\sum_{n=1}^{10000}(X_n)$. Thats a good method. This is probably implemented wrong because you first sample 10000 paths if I'm correct and then take the error.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine $abs(X_N-X_T)$ has shape of $(5, 3, 10000)$ and I take mean along third axis. This leaves me with a $5\times3$ matrix where each row represents different $\Delta t$ and each column represents mean of absolute error of $x$, $y$, and $z$. I am not sure how should I incorporate norm into this. Also, I do not understand why sampling 10000 realizations of Winere process is an issue. I do this for only strong convergence as I was told that $X_T$ and $X_N$ should be computed using same realization of Wiener process.

Comment: The norm reshapes your $5 \times 3$ matrix to a $5 \times 1$ matrix. This is more standard but I had thought about your componentwise attempt and strong convergence with order $j$ in your attempt is identical to strong convergence with order $j$ in the $1$-norm. Your setup is fine, also the way you take the mean which I didn't understand correctly and your use of the exact same realizations of your wiener process is exactly the right setup. Sampling 10000 realizations is no problem it's also the right way.

Comment: To sum up your setup seems completely correct from what you described. I'm sorry I couldn't help you. I did the same strong error estimation for convergence orders of Milstein and Euler in my master thesis. From there I can tell you my estimations clearly converged to the theoretic result. The least squares method gave me something like $0.48$ and $0.96$ for Euler-Maruyama resp. Milstein. While looking at the order of convergence pairwise, not with least squares, for the finer grids the rates almost exactly coincided with the theoretic bounds.

Comment: @Keine_Maschine That's fine. I appreciate your time and effort anyway. Maybe this is due to non-linearity of the system. I will keep explore what I might have done wrong or why these behaviors arise.

Comment: It might be that your noise/stochastic term is too large for the system and step size. Note that for the non-stochastic Lorenz system and higher-order methods the useful step sizes start from $0.05$, so the reference solution as it is might not be precise enough. You could scale the stochastic term down by a factor of 100 or so and look what happens.